# What is fastest way to calculate factorial in common lisp?

Tags: performance, algorithm, common-lisp

What is fastest way to calculate factorial in Common Lisp? For start there is end-tail recursion

```
(defun factorial (n &optional (acc 1))
(if (<= n 1)
   acc
   (factorial (- n 1) (* acc n))))
```

But it is fastest possible way?

Comment: Maybe your compiler is smart enough to transform it to tail recursion.

Comment: @knivil: Maybe the compiler makes it a loop?

Comment: I doubt that this question is specific to Common Lisp;  the fastest (but how do you define fastest?  absolute time? asymptotic (O(…))? least resource intensive?) way to compute a factorial would probably be similar in most languages/implementations.

Comment: Algorithm a is faster than algorithm b for input n if you use them on same computer (vesrion of CL etc. etc. ect.) and algorithm a take less computing time than algorithm b. If algorithm a if faster than b for every possible input n than it is faster. This is my view of faster. This leads to table of results but that is not doable. So I am looking for some solution that is programmable an can be used on PC with standard buyable equipment.

Comment: If you hold to a strict interpretation of "for every possible input", you're not going to get any suitable answers.  Algorithms that work well for big numbers may not be ones that work well for small numbers.  One might perform fewer operations, but require more memory, and disk caching could become an issue.  There are lots of issues like this.  You're unlikely to find a single algorithm that outperforms all others for all inputs.  This is why we use O(…) notation.  Below some threshold, an O(n^2) algorithm might be faster than an O(n) algorithm, but won't be after that threshold.

Comment: Aside from from what was posted by Joni, there are some typical things you'd usually do to micro-optimize your code. Type annotations. This allows the compiler to better understand what you've written. `-`, `*`, and `<=` are generic functions, but you probably don't want them to be so. You don't want optional arguments either. You also want to multiply smaller numbers first. Say, if you could first multiply all powers of two, then multiply all numbers divisible by something, then something else etc. And then in the end multiply all of them together, you'd get better benchmark.

Comment: Then it would be nice to have a set of algorithms for small, medium and big numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implemented the naive algorithm for computing factorials. There are several with better asymptotic performance, see for example http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm

The fastest ones are based on the prime factorization of the factorial.

Comment: Does better asymptotic performance for the actual calculation really matter, though? My wild guess would be that the cost of memory allocation is dominating over the actual calculation for large enough arguments.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lisp; is it not possible to allocate the necessary memory in the beginning and use destructive operations to modify it? Still I would expect memory allocation to be cheaper than integer multiplication which is the slow part of any factorial algorithm.

Comment: The problem is, `BigInteger`s (actually called `bignum`s in Lisp) are allocated automatically in the required size and I don't know of a way to hook into that process, no. If you say that the actual integer multiplication is always the slow part, I will believe you, though you have to consider that the complexity calculations for factorial algorithms are probably usually "blind" to the actual costs of `BigIntegers`s/`bignum`s.

Comment: Typically you have to use an independent library to get good performance in these tasks anyway; standard libraries tend to be implemented with an eye on safety and reliability and fast arbitrary precision arithmetic is not a priority. I'm sure there are exceptions though, apparently some lisp implementations use GMP which is pretty good.

Comment: Yes, at least GNU Common Lisp (CGL) uses GMP for its `bignum` support. Its documentation is not clear if it exposes any GMP functionality beyond what's required by the CL standard library, though, like GMP's own factorial implementation.

Comment: I do not trust algorithm benchmarks in managed languages. Okay I do not trust benchmarks at all.